# Is Hopkinson's Law Valid for Toroids?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Hopkinson's law which states that $$\Phi_B \mathcal{R} = \mathcal{F} = NI$$
Where $\Phi_B$ is magnetic flux, $\mathcal{R}$ is reluctance which only depends on the geometry and material of the object in consideration and $\mathcal{F}$ is magnetomotive force or mmf.

This law is said to be analogous to ohm's law specifically Ohm's law has a linear relationship between $\vec{J}$ and $\vec{E}$ and this law has a linear relationship between $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{H}$ i.e. $\vec{B} = \mu \vec{H}$ (assuming a linear magnetic material) just like $\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E}$. From this analogy a formula for reluctance is developed similar to Ohm's law $\mathcal{R} = \frac{l}{\mu A}$.

Now the problem I have is this analogy being applied to toroids. I think this analogy should only work when $\vec{H}$ is curl-free so that it's possible to define a scalar potential $\vec{H} = -\nabla \psi$ similar to electric potential in electric analogue so that it satisfies laplace's equation $\nabla^2 \psi = 0$ like $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$ like in the electric case. This is exactly what happens in say a solenoid but in toroids the $\oint{\vec{H} \cdot d\vec{l}} \ne 0$ so this analogy should not work yet I've been taught and seen books that still use it [1]. Now I do agree that the relationship $$\Phi_B \frac{l}{\mu A} = NI$$ should hold but based on my conclusion it looks like an accident.

[1] Hughes, E., Hiley, J., McKenzie-Smith, I., & Brown, K. (2016). Hughes electrical and electronic technology (12th ed.). Pearson Education.